# jQuery slideDown for 2 html cases

Tags: jquery, slidedown

Here I have example of my checkbox slideDown solution. http://jsfiddle.net/kNpYz/3/

When you check the checkbox so some elements will slideDown or slideUP and it works fine, but when I change HTML on this. I know that I must change jQuery markup but I don't know how.

```
<div id="section-uvitaci_text" class="section section-checkbox ibutton">
  <h3 class="heading">Uvítací text</h3>
  <div class="option">
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="hidden" class="fld checkbox aq-input" name="uvitaci_text" id="uvitaci_text" value="0">
      <div class="ibutton-container">
        <input type="checkbox" class="fld checkbox of-input" name="uvitaci_text" id="uvitaci_text" value="1" checked="checked">
        <div class="ibutton-handle" style="left: 50px; ">
          <div class="ibutton-handle-right">
            <div class="ibutton-handle-middle"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ibutton-label-off"><span style="margin-right: -50px; ">
          <label>OFF</label>
          </span></div>
        <div class="ibutton-label-on" style="width: 54px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; "><span style="margin-left: 0px; ">
          <label>ON</label>
          </span></div>
        <div class="ibutton-padding-left"></div>
        <div class="ibutton-padding-right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="explain">This will show an offline message. Except for administrators, nobody will be able to access the site</div>
    <div class="clear"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So effect doesn't work. What I must change in my js for this HTML case?

Thx for your time

Answer (score 0):

use this jQuery code:

```
  jQuery('.fld').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.option').find('.explain').slideToggle('normal', "swing");
  });
```

Comment: HTML is generated by this plugin http://www.givainc.com/labs/ibutton_jquery_plugin.htm

thx for your code :)

Comment: @user13746 so if it is auto generated html, use edited jquery code

Comment: and is possible to write something like this? 

.find('f_'+this.id)

Comment: Here is my edited HTML to see what I want to slideDown and slideUp

http://jsfiddle.net/2EA8a/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML has many errors like there cant be two controls with same Id and the ID you sliding in jquery does not exist, try this:

[Correct code](http://jsfiddle.net/JfrRV/1/)